# IE8 and previous Internet Explorer versions

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I've been learning code for a while now, and I keep coming across notes at the bottom of tutorial and manual pages saying "this isn't covered/won't work in previous versions of Internet Explorer." I've started to wonder, does it really matter? I don't want to sound open-ended or off-topic and what-not, but I'm seriously wondering if more than .5% of the population uses old versions of IE8. Furthermore, I'm building a financial website where users could potentially enter in financial information in a dangerous manners. If a person isn't Internet-savvy enough to have at least updated their Internet Explorer, I would think they would not be my target audience.

So, to not be off-topic or open ended, and to stay relevant, I am asking:

1. Is any notable (more than .5%) amount of the Internet-using population using older versions of IE?
2. Is any notable amount of the Internet-using population using IE?
3. Is there any good reason for a user to have not updated their internet browser (i.e. do public libraries not update in some places because it would take time to update every computer)?

Comment: unfortunately we cant just ignore IE because its shitty and we dont like it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is any notable (more than .5%) amount of the Internet-using population using older versions of IE?**

Yes, see [here](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0). Anyone still using XP (a lot of people) can't update past 8 without upgrading their OS to vista or 7. This has kept a lot of users (especially businesses) on IE 8.

**Is any notable amount of the Internet-using population using IE?**

See link above

**Is there any good reason for a user to have not updated their internet browser (i.e. do public libraries not update in some places because it would take time to update every computer)?**

As I said, Updating to a later version of IE isn't always available. They could however install firefox or chrome if you'd include that as a solution (which it shouldn't be)

Answer (score 1):

I found this a little while back, that kinda hit it home in terms of how many people in world use an older version of IE;

http://www.ie6countdown.com/

As @DeanOC says there is http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

But also of note is who is actually using IE at all;

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: See my comment to Dean's answer.